# Selecting attributes from multiple vector layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, select, vector-layer

I'm looking for a way to select multiple attributes from about 9-13 vector layers. I downloaded the "Multiple layer selection" plugin, but I get an error.

```
2022-03-22T14:01:20     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:\Users/Gebruiker/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\MultipleLayerSelection\MultiLayerRectangleSelection.py", line 43, in canvasReleaseEvent
              layer.selectByRect(lRect, False)
             TypeError: QgsVectorLayer.selectByRect(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'bool'
```

[image]

Does someone understand why it isn't working?

Comment: Did you check with the plugin provider?

Comment: Which QGIS version is it? Do you need to select by location or by attribute within all those 9-13 vector layers?

Comment: I have qgis 3.22.4. I want to get an overview of the attributes that are within the square that I draw.

Comment: Can you try to reinstall the plugin?

Comment: Reinstalling unfortunately didn't do the job.

Comment: What do you mean by overview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the Multilayer Select tool worked after a reboot and placing my final files in a new Qgis project.

However, to get the result I wanted I simply had to use the Identify Features Tool. I did not realise you could do more than click on a seperate feature, but instead make a selection by drawing a box. This gives me the "overview" that I wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a new polygon layer. Draw a polygon that covers the area from where you want to get the attributes. Use the following expression without any adaption to get **all attributes from all features of all layers** within this polygon:

```
array_to_string (
    array_foreach (
        @layers,
        with_variable (
            'currentlayer',
            layer_property(@element, 'name'),
            array_to_string(
                array_foreach (
                    generate_series(
                        0, 
                        array_length(
                            overlay_intersects(
                                @currentlayer,
                                $id
                            )
                        )-1
                    ),
                    map_to_hstore( 
                        attributes(
                            get_feature_by_id( 
                                @currentlayer,
                                overlay_intersects(
                                    @currentlayer,
                                    $id
                                )[@element]
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: the label in the red box is created based on the expression above. It contains all key:value pairs (attribute name/attribute value) of all features that intersect the polygon outlined in red, taking into consideration all layers:*

[image]